# How to use a providers from another solution .Net Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

It`s my solutions

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IEventProvider _eventProvider;

        public HomeController(IEventProvider eventProvider)
        {
            _eventProvider = eventProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(eventProvider));
        }

        public Task<List<EventModel>> Index()
        {
            return this._eventProvider.GetEvents(10, 1, 0, null, null, null);
        }
    }
```

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUserModel, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            ...

            services.AddScoped<ITwoFactorProvider, TwoFactorProvider>();
            services.AddScoped<IEmailProvider, EmailProvider>();
            services.AddScoped<IProfileProvider, ProfileProvider>();
            services.AddScoped<IEventProvider, EventProvider>();
        }
        
        ...
    }
}
```

And if I try to contact the provider from the controller, the error falls
I'm a beginner so don't judge strictly

[enter image description here][3]

Please tell me how you can solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you registered IEventProvider in namespace WebApplication1. But your HomeController located in GoldishCMS project. Try to move your Controller into Correct project, and register deps there.
And add services.AddControllers() into Startup.cs

Comment: Не вариант, так как я хочу сделать два проекта, которые будут вызывать провайдеры из WebApplication1 (в дальнейшем переименую). В данном случаи, я хотел сделать WebApplication1 как DateLayer и его дёргать с разных проектов

Answer (score 0):

You must register IEventProvider in your GoldishCMS project startup. Like you did in WebApplication1 project.

Just add code below to Startup.cs in GoldishCMS;

```
   ...
   services.AddScoped<IEventProvider, EventProvider>();
   ...
```

But you can read more articles about [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [IoC](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/internals-of-builtin-ioc-container-in-aspnet-core).

Have a good day.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't help

Error Message:
"Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: WebApplication1.Providers.Interfaces.IEventProvider Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: WebApplication1.Providers.EventProvider': Unable to resolve service for type 'GoldishCMS.Context.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate..."

Comment: Your EventProvider use ApplicationDbContext ?

Comment: Yes, in the provider I access the context and get the data

Comment: So, yo must register ApplicationDbContext in GoldishCMS project too.